# Winforms Listview checkedItems missing

Tags: winforms, listview

Basically, I have a listview inside my form. In order to make the process of selecting the different items in the listview quicker, i have to add a "select all items" checkbox.

```
For Each lvItem As ListViewItem In Me.lvwDatos.Items
lvItem .Checked = True
Next
```

That's about it, very simple. Once i click on the select all checkbox, i can see clearly how all the elements go into checked state. However, on the next step, when i want to loop through the selected items in my code and do whatever tasks should be applied to them, i'm finding that ALL elements are unchecked. What's making them loose their state?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind, i found the problem...that's how it is supposed to be, there's no problem in the listview, it's just the chain of events that were taking place that broke it all...legazy code, as usual...

Answer (score 0):

This is why I have designed [Better ListView component](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) which have this behavior fixed (and many other quirks of .NET ListView).

There is also a free [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express), if you are interested.

The checked item collection is maintained separately and you always get its actual state.